# Blazor wasm delete table row causes sub-component re-rendering

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to figure out how to prevent re-rendering of a sub-component in a `<table>`

I have the typical `WeatherForecast` FetchData example except I've added a button to delete a row in the table, and a column that uses a sub-component that binds (two-way) to a property on the `WeatherForecast` this simulates a problem that I have in my real project except the sub-component has an expensive API call in `OnParametersSet`

```
FetchData.razor
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazorPortfolio.Shared
@using System.Collections.ObjectModel
@using BlazorPortfolio.Client.Components
@inject HttpClient Http

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
    </p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><button @onclick="((item) => HandleDeleteClicked(item, forecast))"></button></td>
                <td><TestComponent @key="@forecast.ForecastId" @bind-ForecastName="@forecast.Summary"></TestComponent></td>
                <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private ObservableCollection<WeatherForecast> forecasts = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
        foreach(var forecast in forecasts)
        {
            this.forecasts.Add(forecast);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Loaded {forecasts.Length} forecasts");
    }

    private void HandleDeleteClicked(MouseEventArgs obj, WeatherForecast clickedForecast)
    {
       forecasts.Remove(clickedForecast); 
    }

}
```

```
TestComponent.razor.cs

using BlazorPortfolio.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorPortfolio.Client.Components;

public partial class TestComponent 
{
    private Guid ComponentInstance { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public string ForecastName { get; set; }
    // property ForecastNameChanged
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ForecastNameChanged { get; set; }
    
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.ComponentInstance = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine($"TestComponent.OnInitialized()");
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TestComponent.OnParametersSet()");
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

On first page load, this is what is logged, which is what I would expect, it loads the forecasts and generates rows (and the TestComponents for each row)

[image]

Now when I press delete I would expect nothing to happen for the TestComponents I'm not removing, but it seems they are instead re-created, 4 sets of logs one for each forecast left.

[image]

I thought using `@key=forecast.ForecastId` would prevent that but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
WeatherForecast.cs

namespace BlazorPortfolio.Shared;

public class WeatherForecast
{
    public Guid ForecastId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public string? Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

Is there any way to prevent the re-creation of the sub-components? I've read you can override the `ShouldRender` but wanted to see if there was another way to get Blazor's change detection to work with me here.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/element-component-model-relationships?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Try adding the `@key="@forecast.ForecastId"` to the main parent of the loop, which is your `<tr>`.

Comment: @RBee adding it to the tr did the trick!

<tr @key="@forecast.ForecastId"></tr>

tyvm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@key` attribute in Blazor is used to help the framework understand how to efficiently render lists of components or elements. It is used by Blazor to determine how to update the DOM with regards to dynamic changes of the elements such as adding and removing.

The scope of the `@key` typically needs to be on the parent element of the loop item. [Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/element-component-model-relationships?view=aspnetcore-8.0#scope-of-key)

So in your example,
instead of adding the `@key` attribute to the child element/component `<td><TestComponent @key="@forecast.ForecastId"` you should add it to the parent element of the loop which is the `<tr>`

```html
@foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
{
    <tr @key="@forecast.ForecastId">
        <td><button @onclick="((item) => HandleDeleteClicked(item, forecast))"></button></td>
        <td><TestComponent @bind-ForecastName="@forecast.Summary"></TestComponent></td>
        <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
        <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
        <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
    </tr>
}
```